# What is the difference between activity and event in "simulation"?

Tags: electrical-engineering, modeling, simulation, computer-engineering

I am studying about components of a system. The subject is "system simulation/simulation modeling/discrete event system simulation". This is related to electrical, electronics, computer science, mathematics, mechanical engineering, physics etc. So,I decided to ask it here after asking in another stackexchange 2 weeksa go.

**Activity-:**

It is What entities do to cause changes is activity. It is represented by time period of a specified length.

**Event-:**

Event is defined as an instantaneous occurrence that might change state of the system. Endogenous events occurs within the system and exogenous events occurs outside the system.

eg-: making a deposit is an activity, arrival of customer is an exogenous event and completion of service of a customer is an endogenous event.

I don't see any difference between them. making deposits can also be an event as it'll change the state of the system. i.e money in bank account. **Does activity not change the state of the system?**

*The one difference that can be taken from these definitions is "instantaneous" vs "time period' but the examples don't deliver anything about it.*

I get a kind of sense that activity(in soccer/football) is like running till the goal post,passing the ball by midfielders and event is scoring a goal. Am I correct? Plus due to lack of resources in my country, I can't cross-verify and analyze it.

Another thing about the same topic that is confusing is that, that quora answer says "You could've number of activities in an event". This isn't very clear to me. Should not activity have many events? But again that makes things even complicated and like a thread which is stuck from many sides and is harder to unscrew it.

Below is the figure from a slide available online for more context.

[image]

Although it might seem like I'm asking multiple questions, my goal is to just learn the difference. I just wanted to give microscopic view on my doubts.

References-:

1. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-event-and-an-activity-in-simulation

Comment: In event based simulation event is the point when activites change. So you have a different activity on both sides of the event time. Wether the action on either side of the event boundary is modelled as instantaneus or not does not make any difference. Activity may change the system but the event changes activity. Imagine ball bouncing the hit on the floor is an event since the integration state of the physics simulation suddenly change. Sure we could simulate entire thing as a continious thing but that would yeld more or less the same result for a lot of overhead.

Comment: For parctical reasons you may not actually have states outside of events. So you could calculate the full analytical ball bounce at the event scedule next event and directly skip to that time. Or you might not.